# Optimizing SQL SERVER 2005 query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Good morning,

I got this part of a SQL query:

```
WITH HC AS (
    SELECT Dia, Mes, Anyo, Hora, Energia AS HidroConv 
    FROM Calendar 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OMP_PDBC_STOTA O 
        ON Calendar.Y = O.Anyo AND Calendar.M = O.Mes 
        AND Calendar.D = O.Dia AND Calendar.H = O.Hora 
    WHERE (Codigo = 1) AND Calendar.dt BETWEEN '12/31/2013' AND '01/01/2014')

SELECT Calendar.dt AS Fecha, Calendar.Y, Calendar.M, Calendar.D, Calendar.H, 
       HC.HidroConv
FROM Calendar 
LEFT OUTER JOIN HC 
     ON Calendar.Y = HC.Anyo AND Calendar.M = HC.Mes 
     AND Calendar.D = HC.Dia AND Calendar.H = HC.Hora 
WHERE dt BETWEEN '12/31/2013' AND '01/01/2014' 
ORDER by dt, h
```

On the WITH part, I have got another 12 queries. Then, on the SELECT part, I retrieve one column per SELECT on the WITH part. On the FROM part, there is a LEFT OUTER JOIN for each one of them, always having Calendar on the left side of the join.

The execution of this big query is taking more than 2 minutes, and I desperately need to reduce that time to, maybe 15 seconds or less. Some of the tables, like OMP_PDBC_STOTA have 3 million rows.

Do you have any idea about how to optimize this query??

Thank you so much for your help.

Ricardo

Comment: First simplify the query - if you are going to do a dozen self joins on `Calendar` using the same fields, CTEs aren't going to make it easier, faster or prettier. Then apply the proper indexes, at least on the fields used for JOINs. I'm sure there's an easier way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to do, but you don't mention what it *is* you are trying to do

Comment: Hi Panagiotis! All I need is to get: Date, Year, Month, Day, Hour, and then a list of several values coming from the same OMP_PDBC_STOTA. I get each value according to a different Codigo in that table. So, for Codigo = 2 I will be getting another value that comes from Energia as well.

Comment: That's a description of what you are trying to write, not what you are trying to do. Are you trying to group some set of fields by category and hour? Why not a simple join then? Are you trying to unpivot the values, ie convert them to rows instead of columns?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to unpivot the values, depending on the Codigo each one has, so I have all of them on the same row together with the date. These values are all coming from OMP_PDBC_STOTA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this query give the same output ?

```
SELECT Calendar.dt AS Fecha, Calendar.Y, Calendar.M, Calendar.D, Calendar.H, Energia AS HidroConv
FROM Calendar 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OMP_PDBC_STOTA O 
        ON Calendar.Y = O.Anyo AND Calendar.M = O.Mes 
        AND Calendar.D = O.Dia AND Calendar.H = O.Hora 
WHERE  
    Calendar.dt BETWEEN '12/31/2013' AND '01/01/2014' 
    AND Codigo = 1
ORDER by dt, h
```

If so, it will be faster, tell me if i'm wrong i'll help you.

Comment: It is hard to say, sometimes it becomes faster and sometimes not. Depends on how many queries the DB is attending at each moment I guess.

Comment: I created an index on OMP_PDBC_STOTA for the fields Anyo,Mes,Dia and Hora, and the query went from 15 seconds to 0       :D :D :D    thanks a lot

Comment: Yes indexes on fields of clause condition join are really important. Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out I don't really need Calendar to get to the same results.

What do you think about this way of doing it?

```
SELECT  anyo, mes, dia, hora, Energia AS HidroConv
FROM OMP_PDBC_STOTA
WHERE  
    CAST(CAST(mes AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(dia AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(anyo AS VARCHAR) as datetime) BETWEEN '12/31/2013' AND '01/01/2014' 
    AND Codigo = 1
ORDER by mes,dia, hora
```

Can't find a proper way of converting the smallints (mes,dia,anyo) to a datetime though.